# Printing a 3D three dimensional variable in Pyomo (3 indexes)

Tags: python, pyomo

I am working on an optimization problem and I have different 3D variables as an output. I want to print my variable in a format table but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Here is an example of my variables:

```
model.zeta= Var(model.I,model.J,model.T,within=Binary) #starting time of an activity j of project i
model.eta= Var(model.I,model.J,model.T,within=Binary) #finsih time of an activity j of project i
```

Where:

```
model.I=Set() #set of construction sites
model.J=Set() #set of project activities
model.T=Set()  #set of periods
```

I want to have i & j as my rows and t as my columns, something like this:

[image]

Comment: Anyone can help please ? #pyomo #python

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas and the results from pyomo for this. I will writte an example:

Let's suppose you have modeled your data and solved it as you state it:

```
model.I=Set() #set of construction sites
model.J=Set() #set of project activities
model.T=Set()  #set of periods

model.zeta= Var(model.I,model.J,model.T,within=Binary) #starting time of an activity j of project i
model.eta= Var(model.I,model.J,model.T,within=Binary) #finsih time of an activity j of project i
```

You need to separate your `index` and `columns` for the `pandas DataFrame` and then iterate over your variable to extract the values and fill the `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd
column = model.I*model.J
ind = model.T
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column, index=ind)
for (i,j,t),val in model.zeta.items():
    df.loc[(i,j),t] = val()

#show the data in dataframe
df.head()
```

That should give you a table like this one:

[image: Example of table to show]

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested:
```
column = instance.I*instance.J
ind = instance.T
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column, index=ind)
for (i,j,t),val in instance.zeta.items():
    df.loc[(i,j),t] = val()

#show the data in dataframe
df.head()
```
But I got this error:
```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 1426, in _set_names
    raise ValueError("Names should be list-like for a MultiIndex")

  ValueError: Names should be list-like for a MultiIndex
```

Comment: Can you please edit and show the model you're solving? This piece code works just fine to me